# dot / spacename in args - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am having this issue when ever i am trying to run a command who needs my user name (that has a dot in the middle of it and python won't understand it. (i think that that's my problem tho)

the code

```
 ig = InstagramAPI(args.user.name, args.password)
```

as i said - the username has a "." in the middle of it.

the error

```
ig = InstagramAPI(args.user.name, args.password)
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'user'
```

would appreciate any kind of solution!

Comment: You can't use a dot in a variable name, consider using `user_name` instead.

Comment: Where does `args` come from?

Answer (score 1):

In python (and in any other language) there are some rules for variable naming, and some conventions regarding the naming. While conventions are rules made by us to improve the readability of the code, you can't get around the naming rules.

As per the rules, of python, a variable can have lowercase and uppercase letters, digits and underscore, i.e. a-z, A-Z and _. No other characters are allowed, otherwise the language would not understand the string as a variable name (or as a name in general). Dot, in particular, has a very specific meaning which makes your lines of code rather confusing for the language.

Simply replace dot with underscore, for example, and your problems will get away.

Comment: thank you for the comment. i am trying again without any spaces or dots and it says the same "  ig = InstagramAPI(args.username, args.password)
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'username'"

Comment: Did you try `args.user_name`?

Comment: AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'instagram_username'

Comment: @Souli That is not a naming problem anymore, it is a problem regarding the way you access the data in args. This is hard to answer, since we don't know where args is coming from.